# PostgreSQL and Libpq - Create trigger that prints a line when requirement is not met

Tags: sql, c, postgresql, triggers, libpq

I really need help on this one, it's for my university project and I'm stuck.

The big idea is to create a trigger on a table that if the value requirement is not met it prints a message to the user and doesn't allow the insert statement to proceed.

I already have a doSQL(conn, "query") function that sends the query to the database and prints any results (if any). Any SELECTs, UPDATEs or INSERTs work just fine with this function, however, I have a problem with multiple lines queries.

For example this:

```
doSQL(conn, "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION najnizsza_krajowa() RETURNS trigger AS $$ BEGIN IF NEW.pensja<1500 THEN SELECT 'Pensja poniżej najniższej krajowej'; END IF; RETURN NEW; END; $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ");
```

returns an error saying `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "END"` indicating at `END IF;` (not the later END). After this I have a create trigger statement

```
doSQL(conn, "CREATE TRIGGER pensja_check BEFORE INSERT ON pracownik FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE najnizsza_krajowa();");
```

which I guess should work, but as I keep messing something with my function it only says that the function is missing. What do I do wrong with the function?

EDIT: The doSQL function, as requested:

```
void doSQL(PGconn *polaczenie, char *komenda){
PGresult *rez;

printf("%s\n", komenda);

rez = PQexec(polaczenie, komenda);
printf("Status: %s\n", PQresStatus(PQresultStatus(rez)));
printf("Komunikaty: %s\n", PQresultErrorMessage(rez));

switch(PQresultStatus(rez)) {
case PGRES_TUPLES_OK:
printTuples(rez);
break;
case PGRES_FATAL_ERROR:
printf("Coś nie tak!");
break;
}
PQclear(rez);
}
```

Sorry for some polish names, hope this won't matter much.
Thanks in advance for any help, this is really important for me.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use psql or PgAdmin to submit your create statement?

Comment: Yes, it is required for my project. I know, kind of stupid, but I can't do anything about it.

Comment: When I run your create function in PgAdmin with only removing the starting double quote and ending double quote it creates without error.  You need to provide the source to doSQL.

Comment: @Bob Edited the question, now it contains the doSQL function.

Comment: Okay, after looking at the first line for a long time I noticed where I made a mistake. `SELECT 'Pensja poniżej najniższej krajowej'` should be `SELECT \'Pensja poniżej najniższej krajowej\'`. This is what messed everything up.

Ps: As I cannot answer my questions now I will post the answer here and do it the right way after 8 hours (low reputation limit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [unescaped single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790497/postgresql-and-libpq-create-trigger-that-prints-a-line-when-requirement-is-not#comment34751305_22790497) you detected are *not* the problem. You cannot `SELECT` in a plpgsql function without a target. You would use [`PERFORM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT) for that, but that's still not what you want. [`RAISE` an `EXCEPTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html):

To do this:

> prints a message to the user and doesn't allow the insert statement to proceed.

Use instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION najnizsza_krajowa()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
IF NEW.pensja < 1500 THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Pensja poniżej najniższej krajowej';
END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Or you could `RAISE` a `WARNING` and `RETURN NULL;` to avoid the rollback.

And do not quote the language name: `'plpgsql'`. It's an identifier, not a string.